# Why is my cursor infinitely looping on the last row

Tags: c++, sql, c

Hello I've been trying to use a cursor with embedded sql in c but I can't seem to get it to stop reading the last row in my table.  The table is called publication with two attributes pubid and title.  I just want my cursor to iterate through and display the pubid.
This is what i have:

```
    EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT pubid FROM publication;
    EXEC SQL OPEN C1;
    while(SQLCODE !=100){
        EXEC SQL FETCH C1 INTO :pubid; //a host variable that was declared earlier
        cout<<pubid<<endl;
    }
```

When I run, it displays all the rows and infinitely repeats displaying the last row.  I tried displaying the SQLCODE as well and it remains 0, so I'm not sure why the cursor doesn't move past the last row

Comment: Its been years I worked on similar things.  But are you missing `SQL` and a terminating `;` in line #4?

Comment: Ah my bad, I typed that out off the top of my head very quickly and didn't notice.  But the problem still persists

Comment: You should also probably use: `while (SQLCODE == 0)` since an error condition won't be caught by your current code. Probably not relevant for your current case since you say it's always 0 but it's something you should look at for robust code.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT pubid FROM publication;
EXEC SQL OPEN C1;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND GOTO close_c1;
while(SQLCODE !=100) {
    EXEC SQL FETCH C1 INTO :pubid;
    cout<<pubid<<endl;
}
close_c1:
EXEC SQL CLOSE C1;
```

Something like this should work.  Also consider using `EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR clean_up_function;` to be able to print out diagnostics.  I found references [here](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~frans/Notes/embeddedSQL.html).

Comment: Your way was actually my first attempt, but for some reason the compiler would give me this error: label 'close_c1' used but not defined so I decided to go this way

Comment: Can't come up with any reason why that error should occur.  Is the label defined in the same function as it is called from?  Defining the label outside the block of a for loop or while loop is OK.

Comment: Yea the label is in the same function